# Draw a line in a div

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div that is a line. Here is my HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link href="clickable.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body >
        <div class="line"></div>
    </body >
</html>
```

And here my CSS:

```
.line{
    width: 112px;
    height: 47px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

Nothing is displaying, something is probably wrong in my CSS, but I can't see what.

Comment: You don't need the <style>-tags in the CSS-file

Comment: Removed the style tag actually worked, how come?

Comment: The style-tag is for inline-styling.. If you want to add style directly in your HTML. when you load a CSS-file, the browser know that it is CSS.

Comment: @rblarsen not inline css style tag for internal css. inline is which you use directly in html tag.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Its working for me

```css
 .line{
width: 112px;
height: 47px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 35):

No need for css, you can just use the HR tag from HTML

```
<hr />
```

Answer (score 10):

```js
$('.line').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
.line {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr class="line"></hr>
<p>click the line</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the div has some content inside, this will be the best practice to have a line over or under the div and maintaining the content spacing with the div

```
.div_line_bottom{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
 padding-bottom:20px;
}

.div_line_top{
border-top: 1px solid #ff0000;
padding-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered this just to emphasize **@rblarsen** comment on question :

> You don't need the **style**  tags in the CSS-file

If you remove the **style** tag from your css file it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You change position absolute to relative

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).